# Handling multi-language paragraph font style in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I have a webpage, which consists of mostly Persian content, and in some paragraphs there is a word or some words in English. The content is generated automatically and I can't change it from my HTML source.
I need to detect where these English words are, and give them `font-size:xx;` The reason of the former is that my English font - which I haven't chosen and changing it would be out of the question- looks bigger than my Persian font and it has to be some pixels less than the font-size I assigned to Persian font of every page.
here goes an example:

```
<span class="common">سلام دنیا (helo world)</span>
```

This whole span receives the following style:

```
.common{
    font-size:26px;
    font-family:'Arial'; 
}
```

and I can't assign a different font-size to the "hello world" part.

Since the page content is produces via a script code which gets data from DB, I can't manually give English words any embedded style, like surrounding them with `<em lang="en"></em>` tag. 
Is there any way to automatically detect English words and give them style- by assigning a class maybe?-

Any attempt to help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How do you detect an english word? Any character that exists in ASCII or ISO-8859-1?

Comment: @PeterMader well according to this link, there is a range of characters for each language. https://unicode-table.com/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate `DOM` by searching for English char sequence and wrap those sequence with your own `span`.

This is not the complete solution, but you can do something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("span").forEach(function(el){
  el.innerHTML = el.innerText.replace(/[a-z]+/g, '<span class="uncommon">$&</span>');
});
```

```css
.common{
    font-size:26px;
    font-family:'Arial'; 
}

.uncommon{
  font-size:36px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<span class="common">سلام دنیا (helo world)</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer works. Just for further usage, I provide an Angular version of this idea. Hope this would help someone in future.

```
.directive( 'showData', function ( $compile ) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
            var el;
            var farsi = 0;

            attrs.$observe( 'template', function ( tpl )
            {
                //var tpl = attrs.template;
                //if ( angular.isDefined( tpl ) )
                {
                    // compile the provided template against the current scope
                    //now work on tpl:

                    function containASCII(str){
                        var flag_only_ascii = 1;
                        var flag_contain_ascii = 0;
                        for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){

                            if(str.charCodeAt(i)<127){
                                flag_contain_ascii = 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                flag_only_ascii = 0;
                            }
                        }

                        if(flag_only_ascii == 1 && flag_contain_ascii == 0)
                            return 1; //just ascii

                        if(flag_only_ascii == 0 && flag_contain_ascii ==1)
                        {
                            return 2;//combination
                        }

                        if(flag_only_ascii == 0 && flag_contain_ascii == 0){
                            return 0; //just english...
                        }

                        if(flag_only_ascii == 1 && flag_contain_ascii == 1){
                            return 3; //other
                        }


                    };

                    if(scope.TranslationValue == 1)
                    {
                        var split_span = tpl.split(" ");
                        for (i = 0 ; i < split_span.length ; i++)
                        {
                            var str_1 = split_span[i];
                            if(containASCII(str_1) == 3){
                                //if(str_1.search("<em2 ") == -1)
                                split_span[i] = "<em2 class='uncommon'>" + str_1 + "</em2>";
                            }
                        }

                        var final_str = split_span.join(" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        final_str = tpl;
                    }


                    final_str = '<span rep-eng-text-font>' + final_str + '</span>';



                    element.html(final_str);

                    // add the template content

                }
            });
        }
    };
})
```